# How to rewrite a voltage source in terms of a cosine function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, voltage

How do I rewrite the voltage source $$v(t) = 10\sin\left(1000\pi t + \frac{\pi}3\right)$$ in terms of a cosine function?

Comment: This is a pure mathematical question. You must post these Q on trigonometry label on MSE.

Comment: Learn trigonometry. If you have now "forgotten" elementary stuff like this, you never learned it in the first place.

Comment: @S.M.T I don't think we should waste Math SE's time on something this basic.

Comment: @StephenG I agree. I think the Q will look much better if the OP had put some of his own efforts too. He would have had also got his mistake rectified + maybe some new method or approach from someone as well.

Answer (score 4):

This might help

$$\cos (\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin\theta$$